# OOP inheritance execution

Tags: java, oop, class

Why does the execution of TestClass.main() outputs 202 202 101??

```
class BaseClass
{
    int data = 101;
    public void print()
    {
        System.out.print(data + " ");
    }
    public void fun()
    {
        print();
    }
}
class SubClass extends BaseClass
{
    int data = 202;
    public void print()
    {
        System.out.print(data + " ");
    }
}
class TestClass
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        BaseClass obj = new SubClass();
        obj.print();
        obj.fun();
        System.out.print(obj.data);
    }
}
```

With my poor OOP knowledge I think the execution must be this way:

1- obj.print(); prints 202 from SubClass

2- Since there is no obj.fun(); method in Subclass it calls parent method so the output should be 101

3- System.out.print(obj.data); should print 202 since the value is overridden in subclass.

So I think the output would be 202 101 202 but it isn't, can you explain me why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Since there is no obj.fun(); method in Subclass it calls parent method so the output should be 101

Indeed, it calls the super class for `fun`, but the super class calls `print`, and as `print` is overridden, the overriding version (in the subclass) gets called.

> System.out.print(obj.data); should print 202 since the value is overwritten in subclass.

Variables are not overriden, but hidden by subclass, as `obj` declared as `BaseClass`, it accesses it `data` property directly. unlike method call, this is decided at compile time.

Comment: Now I get it, thanks Binyamin. I will mark your answer as soon as i can

Answer (score 2):

Because method are polymorphic and fields are not

if you remove

```
int data = 101;
```

from your `BaseClass` it will not compile

Answer (score 1):

The trick is in deciding which method is executed. That choice is made from the type of the instance of the object. In your case, obj is a `SubClass` and every call to `print()` will execute the print method of `SubClass`. This mechanism is called [Polymorphism in OOP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_in_object-oriented_programming).

Instead of mixing methods and variables, I'd recommend you start by just doing some testing on methods only. The code is mostly the same, with the same Polymorphism behavior, but without the variables.

```
class BaseClass
{
    public void print()
    {
        System.out.print(101 + " ");
    }
    public void fun()
    {
        print();
    }
}
class SubClass extends BaseClass
{
    public void print()
    {
        System.out.print(202 + " ");
    }
}
class TestClass
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        BaseClass obj = new SubClass();
        obj.print();
        obj.fun();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1 and 2 - methods are polymorphic - method from `base class` will use method from `sub class`, **if it will be able** and ofc if you have reference to `sub class`

3 - field isnt polymorphic. It's taken from the type of reference.